# Evaluating a column using STRING_SPLIT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a table where one columns contains several email addresses or names in one string:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+
| id ¦ emails                                                ¦
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  ¦ John Doe; jdoe@gmail.com; Company IT; jd@company.com; ¦
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  ¦ jane@company.com; Jane Doe; jd@company.com;           ¦
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to evaluate the emails column to identify whether there are external email addresses (e.g. `jdoe@gmail.com`). So, I need to split the values in the column `emails` into individual strings and evaluate each string. In the end, I'd like to update the table with an additional column indicating whether the emails are internal or external.

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| id ¦ emails                                                ¦ flag      ¦
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 1  ¦ John Doe; jdoe@gmail.com; Company IT; jd@company.com; ¦ external  ¦
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| 2  ¦ jane@company.com; Jane Doe; jd@company.com;           ¦ internal  ¦
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I managed to split a string using `STRING_SPLIT()` and to perform the evaluation I'd like (of a sort).

```
DECLARE @flag int

SELECT @flag=COUNT(*) FROM STRING_SPLIT('John Doe; jdoe@gmail.com; Company IT; jd@company.com;', ';')
WHERE value LIKE '%@%'AND value NOT LIKE '%Company%'

IF (@flag > 0)
BEGIN
Print 'extern'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
Print 'intern'
END
```

However, now I am passing a string to the `STRING_SPLIT()` function. I'd like to pass the column `emails` instead and update the table according to the results of the evaluation. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: The "better" question here is *why* are you storing undefined delimited data in you table in the first place, and why is your final result set not fixing that problem?

Comment: Fix your tables and use proper columns. Storing everything in a single column violates the most basic rule and makes efficient querying (or even *easy* querying) impossible

Comment: On the other hand, suffix queries can't be accelerated by indexes. Instead of splitting you could use [full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) to quickly find rows that *don't* contain a specific search term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a `select` as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when e.cnt > 0 then 'external' else 'internal' end) as flag
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from string_split(t.emails, ';') s
      where value LIKE '%@%' AND value NOT LIKE '%Company%'
     ) e;
```

Note: this keeps the OP's original logic for identifying "internal" versus "external".  The question does not seem to be about that.  Obviously, this version confuses the username and domain components, so the username could actually contain the company name, even though the OP might want it as "external".

Normally, I would warn about storing multiple values in a single column, recommending a more normalized structure -- a table with one email per row.  I do understand that sometimes email list are used just to pass to email programs and need to be in a particular format.  In such cases, they are usually treated as black boxes, and not typically parsed in SQL, so they are a reasonable exception to the rule.

Comment: In this case a full text search index could accelerate the query

Comment: The above would incorrectly flag an email address like `'MyCompany@yahoo.com'` as "internal"? You'd be better off searching for the full domain, preceded by the `@` symbol `'%@Company.com'`.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I added a note to that effect.  I just kept the OP's original logic, because the question does not seem to be about that logic.  As for a full text search, that would need to be handled quite carefully.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed providing the solution I need. Except, now I have a new table but how do I store this table, or overwrite the old table, or just update the old table with the column flag? Regarding the logic in the condition: I only provided the bare minimum because it didn't seem relevant to my actual problem.  I will, indeed, build the conditions a bit differently.

Comment: @corr . . . You can convert this to an `update` with a `from` clause, to update the original table.  If that is not clear, I would recommend asking a new question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for you generous help. Also for your latest hint. Solved my problem.